# How do I enchant in Minecraft PE?

Tags: minecraft-bedrock-edition

I have Minecraft PE on my iPad. I'm trying to make an enchantment but I can't figure out how to do it.

I have made a bookshelf and tried tapping on it but it didn't work as I expected. Are there any solutions?

Comment: I don't get it...

Comment: Seems a fair question, why the down votes?

Comment: Thanks to how poor the Minecraft wikis are when it comes to PE, I got the impression this had changed. As far as I can tell now, it actually hasn't. Doh.

Comment: @AndrewSwan Check the revision history.  The original version of the question was far worse.

Comment: @Studoku - did you bounty too soon?

Comment: @Studoku I was reminded of this question today, so I've updated the answer you bountied with the latest information, so six months later, your bounty had the intended effect :)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I believe you're talking about [enchanting](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Enchanting), which (in the main version) happens at an Enchantment Table (not at a bookshelf, though it is affected by nearby bookshelves).

Enchanting is part of the (currently upcoming) Alpha 0.12.1 release ([Source](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Pocket_Edition_Alpha_0.12.1)).

Comment: It still has not come out.

Answer (score 0):

So far, enchantments are not available on the pocket edition. They should be coming out soon, but in the meantime, bookshelves are just pretty for decoration.

Answer (score 0):

You do not enchant at a bookshelf, you would do this at an Enchantment Table, but this is not yet implemented in Minecraft Pocket Edition.

Answer (score 0):

A bookshelf is only used to increase the enchantment level of enchantments when using an [Enchanting Table](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Enchantment_mechanics#Bookshelf_placement). You can enchant with an enchanting table and some bookshelves, but not vice versa. Villagers (the priest mainly) will enchant your item for a fee of some emeralds as said in the Minecraft Combat Book (Since enchanting is not available, priests will not be able to do this in Minecraft PE. They can only do this in the Full Version).

To craft the table, you need 2 diamonds, 4 obsidian, and a book:

```
  b            #Formation of Material, b = book, d = diamond, o = obsidian
d o d
o o o
```

You access the table as if you were accessing the Furnace or Crafting Table. Enchanting Table has not been released even since its latest update to allow day and night in Creative Mode (as of December 2014 - February 2015). I hope this helps you!

Answer (score 0):

There is no such thing as enchantments in minecraft pe 0.11.1 or earlier. It could be implemented later,though.

Answer (score -1):

Actually they will not be coming out with an enchanting table for another year or 2 se they are already making despensers and new mobs like snowman and they are making it able to where you can place Redstone

Answer (score -1):

As of MCPE 0.10.5 on Android, Fire OS, and MCPE 0.10.4 on iOS and Windows Phone, enchantment of weapons, items and armor has not yet been implemented. It will possibly be added in a future update, as the developers gave a list of features that WILL be eventually added to the Pocket Edition, which you can see here, https://minecraft.wiki/w/Pocket_Edition_mentioned_features
under the 'From the PC version' section of the wiki page.

Have fun playing MCPE! :)