# Is it possible to enchant items in Minecraft: Pocket Edition?

Tags: minecraft-bedrock-edition

During a game of MCPE, I found that I didn't know how anything worked. So I had a simple question about this that also came from a larger write-ups of questions.

**Is it possible to enchant items in MCPE? If so, how do you do it?**

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What "ingredients" do I need to enchant, and how do I get those "ingredients"?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/235900/what-ingredients-do-i-need-to-enchant-and-how-do-i-get-those-ingredients) or [How do I enchant in Minecraft PE?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/172400/how-do-i-enchant-in-minecraft-pe)

Answer (score 3):

Know that this thread is a bit old but yeah, you can now.

Enchanting was added in Alpha 0.12.1 and also brewing, nether, repairing and more.

> Alpha 0.12.1 is an update to Minecraft Pocket Edition that added many new things such as the Nether, brewing, enchanting, hunger, weather, and much more ...
> https://minecraft.wiki/w/Pocket_Edition_Alpha_0.12.1

To enchant stuff (if you don't know it), you need 2 diamond, 4 obsidian and 1  book.

Then the crafting recipes will automatically show up in MC:PE.

Answer (score 2):

No, enchantments are not available currently.

However, enchantment tables will be added in Alpha 0.12.0, with a possible release date in August, [according to the wiki](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Pocket_Edition_Alpha_0.12.0):

> ### Planned additions
>
> - [...]
> - Enchanting<sup>[15][16]</sup>
> - [...]
>
> [...]
>
> 15. https://twitter.com/_tomcc/status/619560509612945408
> 16. https://twitter.com/darngeek/status/621392732636999680

Comment: Looks like it's been added now.

Answer (score 0):

Well depends what version you have. If you have 12.0+ then you may enchant. But below I don't think so. To make an enchanting table is extremely expensive. You need two diamonds,obsidian and a book. That's all I remember off the top of my head.