# What "ingredients" do I need to enchant, and how do I get those "ingredients"?

Tags: minecraft-bedrock-edition

I am new to Pocket Edition, and have no clue how to do enchantments. What sort of materials do I need to enchant?

Comment: Also I am on the latest update for p.e. On my iPad

Comment: It would be better to edit your question with new information, rather than posting it in a comment.

Comment: Also the wiki suggests you only need lapis lazuli and experience to enchant: http://minecraftpocketedition.wikia.com/wiki/Enchantment_Table

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A helpful link can be found [here.](http://minecraftpocketedition.wikia.com/wiki/Enchanting)

To enchant, you need basic items.

- Enchantment table (Crafted with 3 obsidian, 2 diamonds, and one book in a stonecutter)
- The tool you want to enchant
- Lapis Lazuli
- Lots of experience.

Then, click on the enchantment you would like. If all are unsatisfactory, try again.

Helpful items:

- Anvil and enchanted books (a different form of enchanting)
- Bookshelves (When placed around the enchantment table, increase strength of enchantment.

You *can* enchant, but it is very expensive.